How to Implement a Text-Based Question Answering System for PDF Documents using Machine Learning?
As a beginner in machine learning, I've completed a basic text classification project in university. Now, I'm eager to build a system that can answer specific questions from a large collection of PDF documents. What are the essential steps, tools, and techniques to achieve this goal? How should I approach data preparation, model selection, training, evaluation, and deployment for such a project? Any guidance or resources would be highly appreciated. Thanks!
